# Create 'Add Payment Method' button in 'My Account/ Payment Methods' to open a popup mirroring 'Add Payment Method' page

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I want to add a button on the payment methods page that opens the 'Add Payment Method' page as a popup. I've created a shortcode for the 'Add Payment Method' page and embedded it in the popup template. The issue is that JavaScript and CSS for Stripe are only loaded if it's the 'Add Payment Method' page. How can I resolve this? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

***Inside abstract class WC_Payment_Gateway_Stripe extends WC_Payment_Gateway***

```
public function enqueue_frontend_scripts( $page = '' ) {
        if ( $page ) {
            if ( 'product' === $page ) {
                $this->enqueue_product_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            } elseif ( 'cart' === $page ) {
                $this->enqueue_cart_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            } elseif ( 'checkout' === $page ) {
                $this->enqueue_checkout_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            } elseif ( 'mini_cart' === $page ) {
                $this->enqueue_mini_cart_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            } else {
                $this->enqueue_frontend_scripts();
            }
        } else {
            if ( is_add_payment_method_page() ) {
                $this->enqueue_add_payment_method_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            }
            if ( is_checkout() ) {
                $this->enqueue_checkout_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            }
            if ( is_cart() ) {
                $this->enqueue_cart_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            }
            if ( is_product() ) {
                $this->enqueue_product_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
            }
        }
        if ( ! empty( stripe_wc()->scripts()->enqueued_scripts ) ) {
            $this->enqueue_payment_method_styles();
        }
    }
```

So as you can see scripts are only added if page is add payment method page

```
$this->enqueue_add_payment_method_scripts( stripe_wc()->scripts() );
```